# How can I get apache to interpret <? lines as php lines?

Tags: php, apache

I'm inheriting some html/php code.

I've installed apache and php on my windows box. At first, things sort of worked until I realized that php.ini is not being sourced. When I changed the path to the ini file to somewhere other than the "Program Files (x86)" dir, the file is sourced, but the code I'm running stops working.

The code has a bunch of places that say <? foobar ?> instead of <?php foobar?>

I tried googling for '<?' vs '<?php', but it ignored the <? parts.

What configuration do I need telling apache that <? means php?

Comment: You need to make sure you've added the module file in your apache config. Also, make sure you have appropriately setup your mime types.

Comment: hi, take a look here [http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: @RageD - it's a setting in php.ini. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set `short_open_tag = On` in php.ini. However due to conflicts with XML this is generally seen as a bad idea.

Comment: Exactly, and as @CFreak said better leave it off and change <? for <?php on the code

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the best idea. What about creating a script to process the files searching for strings containing `"<?"` without "php" in order to correct them? Using regular expressions it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: indeed, you're right. don't be lazy. using perl: $line =~ s/\<\?(?!php)/\<\?php/g;